# PHP Quiz Radio and Checkbox Calculation

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement, post

I'm designing a simple quiz with PHP and would like to know if i'm approaching it the correct way before proceeding.

The quiz will have approximately 25 questions, a mixture of radio buttons and checkboxes. The idea is to calculate the total and display this to the user when the quiz is submitted.

I have just four questions so far. Questions 1 - 3 are radio buttons, one selection max. Question 4 is a checkbox and allows two selections max, each correct selection is worth 0.5

Here's a snippet of my html code (question and answer text removed).

**HTML**

```
// q1 answer is value 2
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="3">

// q2 answer is value 1
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="3">

// q1 answer is value 2
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="3">

// q4 answer is value 1 or 3. 0.5 points each
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="4">
```

The PHP code below works, is it the correct approach or is there a more efficient way? Specifically with the checkbox question 4.

**PHP**

```
$total = array();

$total = '0';

$q1 = $_POST['form']['1-1'];
$q2 = $_POST['form']['1-2'];
$q3 = $_POST['form']['1-3'];
$q4 = $_POST['form']['1-4'];

// answer with value 2 is correct
if ($q1 == '2' ) {
    $total++;
};
// answer with value 1 is correct
if ($q2 == '1' ) {
    $total++;
};
// answer with value 2 is correct
if ($q3 == '2' ) {
    $total++;
};
// answer with value 1 is correct
if ($q4[0] == '1' ) {
    $total = $total + 0.5;
};
// answer with value 3 is correct
if ($q4[1] == '3' ) {
    $total = $total + 0.5;
};

// send $total to database here
```

I'm not looking to use JS / Jquery, I want to use a PHP approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more dynamic version, which also lends itself to being loaded from a database.

The solutions array has the list of questions and answers, if it is a multiple answer question, then the answer is an array of the correct values.

The loop goes through the solutions and compares the answer against the expected solution.  If the answer is not present, the `?? null` sets it, but it should not match the results.

```
$solutions = ['1-1' => 2, '1-2' => 1, '1-3' => 2, '1-4' => [1,3]];

foreach ( $solutions as $question => $solution ) {
    $userAnswer = $_POST['form'][$question] ?? null;
    if ( is_array($solution) ){
        $marksPerAnswer = 1/count($solution);
        $correct = array_intersect($solution, $userAnswer);
        $total += $marksPerAnswer * count($correct);
    }
    else    {
        $total += ($userAnswer == $solution);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added some alternative code for that at the bottom of the answer.  Normally it may be better to add a new question, especially as this is over a month old.

Comment: thanks I have just posted a question while you were answering this one! See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170058/php-quiz-calculation-of-array-answers Thanks again for the update

Comment: It just helps as the original person who answered may not be around, can give you a quicker (and sometimes) better answer.