# PHP Quiz Calculation of Array Answers

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a quiz designed using html radio buttons and the calculation is handled by some PHP.

See below for the basic html layout (some elements removed for ease of reading);

```
// q1 answer is value 2
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="2">

// q2 answer is value 1
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="2">

// q1 answer is value 2
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="2">

// q4 answer is value 1 AND 2 AND 4
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="4">
```

The PHP code I have currently works (thanks to [PHP Quiz Radio and Checkbox Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540581/php-quiz-radio-and-checkbox-calculation#61540853)), however it splits points on questions with multiple answers.

```
$solutions = ['1-1' => 2, '1-2' => 1, '1-3' => 2, '1-4' => [1,2,4]];

foreach ( $solutions as $question => $solution ) {
    $userAnswer = $_POST['form'][$question] ?? null;
    if ( is_array($solution) ){
        $marksPerAnswer = 1/count($solution);
        $correct = array_intersect($solution, $userAnswer);
        $total += $marksPerAnswer * count($correct);
    }
    else    {
        $total += ($userAnswer == $solution);
    }
}
```

How can I assign one point for fully correct answers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only count fully correct answers, then you can compare the number of expected answers against the number that match, so change the first if part to...

```
if ( is_array($solution) ){
    $correct = array_intersect($solution, $userAnswer);
    $total += (count($solution) == count($correct));
}
```

Comment: The `$marksPerAnswer` was the fractional part of any answer, so with 2 answers `$marksPerAnswer` would be 0.5.  If you want to give multiple marks per answer, then you may need to extend the `$solutions` array to contain another field for this (and extra code to process it).

Comment: Put the `* 5` outside the brackets - `count($correct)) * 5;`

Comment: When you say still doesn't work, it should end up with either 0 or 5 points (5 only if all are correct), is this what you want?

Comment: OK - does multiplying `$total` by 5 after the loop do the same thing?

Comment: I've created another similar question it would be greta if you had the time to suggest an answer, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431857/php-quiz-question-calculations-radios-and-checkboxes