# PHP Quiz Question Calculations Radios and Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a html quiz, the answers are in radio button and checkbox format.

Users must answer **all parts** of the question correctly in order to score full marks, no split points are awarded.

I have 25 questions in my quiz.

A simplified version of the html quiz is below (showing just 4 questions);

```
// q1 answer is value 1
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-1]" value="2">

// q2 answer is value 3
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-2]" value="3">

// q3 answer is value 3
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="form[1-3]" value="3">

// q4 answer is value 1 AND 2 (both correct answers need to be selected)
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="form[1-4][]" value="4">
// etc
```

I need to compare the values submitted in the quiz against an array of pre-defined **correct** answers.

The PHP code I have to check the answers is below;

```
$total = '0';

// if it is a multiple answer question, then the answer is an array of the correct values
// 'question number' => solution
$solutions = [
  '1-1' => 1, 
  '1-2' => 3, 
  '1-3' => 3, 
  '1-4' => [1,2],
  '1-5' => 3,
  '1-6' => [1,4,6],
  '1-7' => 2,
  '1-8' => [1,2],
  '1-9' => 2,
  '1-10' => 1,
  '1-11' => 4,
  '1-12' => 3,
  '1-13' => [2,4],
  '1-14' => 2,
  '1-15' => 1,
  '1-16' => 1,
  '1-17' => [1,2],
  '1-18' => 2,
  '1-19' => 2,
  '1-20' => 1,
  '1-21' => 3,
  '1-22' => 2,
  '1-23' => 1,
  '1-24' => 3,
  '1-25' => 2
];

// The loop goes through the solutions and compares the answer against the expected solution. 
// If the answer is not present, the ?? null sets it,
foreach ( $solutions as $question => $solution ) {
    $userAnswer = $_POST['form'][$question] ?? null;
    if ( is_array($solution) ){
        $correct = array_intersect($solution, $userAnswer);
        $total += (count($solution) == count($correct));
    }
    else    {
        $total += ($userAnswer == $solution);
    }
}

$marksPerAnswer = 5;
$total = $total * $marksPerAnswer;
$_POST['form']['total'] = $total;
var_dump($_POST);
```

The results of `var_dump($_POST)` are;

```
array (
  'form' => 
  array (
    '1-1' => '1',
    '1-2' => '3',
    '1-3' => '3',
    '1-4' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '2',
    ),
    '1-5' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),
    '1-6' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '4',
      2 => '6',
    ),
    '1-7' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-8' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '2',
    ),
    '1-9' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-10' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
    ),
    '1-11' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
    ),
    '1-12' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),
    '1-13' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '3',
    ),
    '1-14' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-15' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
    ),
    '1-16' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
    ),
    '1-17' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
      1 => '3',
    ),
    '1-18' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-19' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-20' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-21' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    '1-22' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),
    '1-23' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),
    '1-24' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),
    '1-25' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
    'total' => 30,
  ),
)
```

I have answered the first ten questions correctly (see my array answers match the array solutions 1-1 to 1-10) however the total is only 30, I should have scored at least 50 for the first ten correct answers?

It looks as though the script isn't counting the multiple answer questions like numbers 4, 6 and 8. I don't know why?

Is my code incorrect, or should I change it in some way in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: According to your $_POST array, everything after 1-5 is returning as an array (even those with a single answer). Therefore they would be captured as such. Don't know if this is the solution, but it would definitely affect the outcome?

Comment: It would be in the html. For your checkboxes, because you are asking for more than one answer, you have added `[]`. This output would be seen if the questions below q4 also had `[]` in there. I am massively assuming though as we cannot see past q4. Only checkbox q's should have extra `[]`...

Comment: In your answers, some of the questions which don't look as though they should be multiple choice have arrays for the users answers.  For example Expected for `'1-5' => 3,` and user input of `'1-5' => 
    array (
      0 => '3',
    ),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks as though there are some issues with things being multichoice or not, this solution converts everything into arrays and then checks if the answer is equal to the solution...

$total = 0;

```
foreach ( $solutions as $question => $solution ) {
    $userAnswer = $_POST['form'][$question] ?? null;
    $solution = is_array($solution) ? $solution : [$solution];
    $userAnswer = is_array($userAnswer) ? $userAnswer : [$userAnswer];
    $total += ($userAnswer == $solution);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - thank you! Can you explain where I was going wrong please so I can learn?

Comment: As I said in the comment, there is something odd about how some of the non-multi choice options seem to be giving arrays as the answer. `'1-5'` for example.  But as you only want full matches, it can be easy to convert everything as though it was a multi choice and then compare the results.